# Class level lock not working as intended

Tags: java, synchronization

I wrote a following program and from my understanding it should not print

`'Didn't hang, it should've.` as `shouldHang` method is static synchronized and i have already taken a class level lock.

I am unable to understand this behavior. Can some one help me on this,

```
public class Test1 {
        synchronized static public void shouldHang() {
            System.out.println("Didn't hang, it should've.");
        }

        static public void main(String args[]) {
            Test1 test = new Test1();
            synchronized (test.getClass()) {
                new Thread(new trylock()).start();
            }

        }
    }

    class trylock implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Test1.shouldHang();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share in wich part are you have taken the lock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why shouldn't it print it? You have a single thread invoking a single synchronized method. The main thread has finished executing (and thus released the lock) when the method is invoked. Starting a thread just starts it and returns immediately, so the sequence of events is:

1. main thread acquires the lock
2. main thread starts another thread
3. main thread releases the lock (and stops running)
4. second thread acquires the lock
5. second thread prints
6. second thread releases the lock (and stops running)

The second thread **might** try acquiring the lock while the main thread still has it, but that doesn't change anything: the main thread releases it, and thus makes it available for the second thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread doesn't hold the lock for the whole lifetime of the try-lock thread. You need to ask the main thread to wait. Then you'll have a deadlock. Is that what you want?

```
synchronized (test.getClass()) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new trylock());
    t.start();
    t.join(); // Now the thread hang, but of course this will only deadlock your program.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.start starts the given thread and then immediately returns; it does not wait for the newly started thread to finish.

In this case, the new thread starts and is blocked, as you say; but immediately afterwards, the main thread returns from the start() method and the synchronized block competes, unblocking the new thread and letting it print its message.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't that be printed?. Your main thread takes the lock only to create and start the second thread and then releases the lock. Then the second thread takes the lock and executes the method. Note that the second thread might indeed be waiting for a "very trivial" time, hence you are not seeing it.

If you really want to see the behavior of *synchronized* here, add a small sleep of 5 seconds after your thread starting block.